# Android Shared Preferences Time Required to Save

Tags: android, localization, sharedpreferences, locale

I am writing locale language data to the shared preferences of my device then resetting the device 5 seconds later.

In my application a user can set the language to English or Spanish. This works. If the device is in Spanish and we try to restore defaults the device will restart but remain in Spanish.
The following is my Locale Controller.

public class LocaleController {

```
private final String LANGUAGE_KEY = "language";
private static ArrayList<Locale> supported_languages = new ArrayList<Locale>();
private static LocaleController localeController = null;
private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = null;

public static LocaleController getInstance(){
    if(localeController == null || sharedPreferences == null){
        localeController = new LocaleController();
        sharedPreferences = Application.getAppContext().getSharedPreferences("PCIApplication", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        String[] resourceLanguages = Application.getAppContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.supported_languages);
        Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();

        for(Locale locale : locales){
            for(String language : resourceLanguages){
                if(locale.getDisplayName().contains(language)) {
                    supported_languages.add(locale);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return localeController;
}

public Locale getCurrentLocale(){
    Resources resources = Application.getAppContext().getResources();
    return resources.getConfiguration().locale;
}

public Locale getDefaultLocale(){
    return Locale.getDefault();
}

public void setLocale(Locale locale){
    Resources resources = Application.getAppContext().getResources();
    Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    if(locale != null) {
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            configuration.setLocale(locale);
        } else {
            configuration.locale = locale;
        }
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration,displayMetrics);
        this.updateLocaleSharedPreferences(locale);
    }
}

public ArrayList<Locale> getSupportedLanguages(){
    return supported_languages;
}

public Locale getLocaleByName(String name){
    Locale locale = null;
    for(Locale entry : supported_languages){
        if(name.equals(entry.toString()) || entry.getDisplayName().contains(name)) {
            locale = entry;
        }
    }
    return locale;
}

public void determineDeviceLanguage(){
    String localeName = sharedPreferences.getString(LANGUAGE_KEY, getDeviceDefaultLocale().toString());
    Locale foundLocale = getLocaleByName(localeName);

    setLocale(foundLocale);
}

private void updateLocaleSharedPreferences(Locale locale){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(LANGUAGE_KEY, locale.toString());
    editor.commit();
}

public void restoreLocaleDefaults(){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.remove(LANGUAGE_KEY);
    editor.putString(LANGUAGE_KEY, Application.getAppContext().getResources().getString(R.string.locale_default));
    editor.commit();
    System.out.println("THE LANGUAGE IS " + sharedPreferences.getString(LANGUAGE_KEY, "RANDOM GARBAGE"));
}

public Locale getDeviceDefaultLocale(){
    String defaultLocale = Application.getAppContext().getResources().getString(R.string.locale_default);
    Locale foundLocale = getLocaleByName(defaultLocale);

    return foundLocale;
}
```

}

On start we use `determineDeviceLanguage()` to find any saved shared preferences or load the default language en_US.

When a user restored defaults on the device `restoreLocaleDefaults()` is called. This first removes the language shared preference then adds the default value. I am using `commit()` to block the current process to ensure we save the data before resetting the device.

When we reset the device we perform a hard reset, power is pulled.

While testing this in debug I can step through the `restoreLocaleDefaults()` function, allow the device to reset and the language is English as expected. If I let this run with no breakpoints the language remains in Spanish.

Comment: What is your desired result? "I set the language to English then reset the device. However when the device restarts it remains in English". When you set language to English and store it in SharedPreferences, it will be persisted, even after a reboot/reset.

Comment: Please post the code that applies the selected language

Comment: @Nulldroid that was a typo on my part. If the device is currently displaying Spanish. If I set the language to English, the device resets itself but remain in Spanish.

Comment: An odd note. I saw this work 4 times in a row. Then it stopped working as expected.

Comment: Your start up code in if(locale != null) also calls this.updateLocaleSharedPreferences(locale). It seems your app starts, and immediately updates SharedPreferences with default locale. If I understand correctly, this is not intended, is it?
To answer your other question: There is nothing wrong with editor.apply(), btw.

Comment: I pasted that in the wrong order, my apologies. When we reset the device we remote the shared preference setting for language. The first thing my Setup Wizard does it determines the language. For some reason the language is returned as Spanish even though in the previous activity we can see it was removed. The default value of English should be found.